# É possível acessar uma porta via TCP/UDP à partir de uma aplicação web?

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, socket, tcp, udp

É possível enviar dados a uma porta (ex: 5151) via TCP ou UDP à partir de um site, no front end, utilizando JavaScript por exemplo.

Estou pesquisando há um tempo e o mais perto que cheguei até agora foi criar um App do chrome utilizando a API [sockets](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket) porém, tive dois problemas com isso.

1º para utilizar a API [sockets](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket) precisa ser um App  ao invés de uma extensão, por tanto precisa ser executado, o que é pouco prático para o usuário final.

2º é que não consegui mandar nenhum tipo de informação para ele da pagina, nada, nem mesmo um "hello world".

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

De forma geral, em aplicação web real, rodando em um navegador padrão, não tem como fazer de forma direta.

É possível usar certos artifícios como [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) que encapsulam TCP dentro do HTTP, o que obviamente perde a principal vantagem do TCP em relação ao HTTP de ser mais eficiente, então você faz funcionar por uma questão de compatibilidade ou porque precisa de algum recurso que o TCP tem, como por exemplo a manutenção de estado da conexão, mas não é o TCP puro. E não será pela porta desejada, será na porta 80.

Se usar um navegador não padrão ou algum *plugin* pode usar esses protocolos de forma direta, mas em geral não será o que quer, não deve fazer muito sentido.

Dependendo do que deseja, deve-se abandonar tecnologia web, ou então se conformar com essa limitação.